# Is there an algorithm to find all subsets of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, algorithms

I'm trying to find a way to find all subsets of a set.

Is there an algorithm  to calculate this?

Comment: Is the set finite?

Comment: Hint: in any given subset, each member of the base set is either in the subset or not in it.  Can you think of a convenient way to map this to a digital representation?

Comment: List them one by one?

Comment: In general, there is not even an algorithm to find all *elements* of a set.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set

Comment: [Nijenhuis and Wilf](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/website/CombAlgDownld.html) give a method for enumerating the subsets of a *finite* set; have a look.

Comment: nicely explained with examples and program: http://javabypatel.blogspot.in/2015/10/all-subsets-of-set-powerset.html

Answer (score 16):

The algorithm in a recursive one. To understand the algorithm consider the following example:

Let $S = \{1,2,3\}$. The subsets of $S$ are all subsets of $\{1,2\}$ and all subsets of $\{1,2\}$ with the element $3$ appended to each subset. 
Essentially, if you know subsets of $\{1,2\}$, the problem can be solved. You can take it from here on.

Comment: What is the name of this algorithm?

Answer (score 9):

An alternative to the recursive formulations provided so far to enumerate the subsets of a finite set is to index the subsets : if $n$ is the number of elements of your set, there are $2^n$ subsets. The subsets can be enumerated iteratively by using a variable `index` ranging from $0$ to $2^n-1$, and using the binary representation of the variable `index` to determine which elements of your base set the current subset has.

Over recursive formulations, this one has the advantage of not risking a stack overflow, which may happen if $n$ is greater than the stack capacity. It also avoids storing lists of subsets if you can process these subsets with a continuation.

Comment: While I didn't want to give a direct answer to what feels quite strongly like a homework question, this is a _much_ better answer than any recursive or combination-based approach.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I fear the homework question as well, and tried not to be too descriptive, I hope this is not going too far. I had not read your comment when I started writing this, however all credit should go to you.

Comment: This is a common interview question. Got asked this twice already. Just leaving a note.

Answer (score 5):

In C, the algorithm explained by Vincent Nivoliers could look like:

```
int main(int size, char * set[]) {

    unsigned int i, j;
    unsigned short bit;
    unsigned int max_bits;  // max bits for number i
    size = size - 1;  // exclude first element

    for (i = 0; i < pow(2, size); i++) {
        printf("{ ");
        max_bits = floor( log2(i) );
        for (j = 0; j <= max_bits; j++) {
            bit = (i >> j) & 1;  // bit value at position j
            if (bit == 1)
                printf("%s ", set[j + 1]);  // one-based array, add 1
        }
        printf("}\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which would for the arguments 1 2 3 produce the output

```
{ }
{ 1 }
{ 2 }
{ 1 2 }
{ 3 }
{ 1 3 }
{ 2 3 }
{ 1 2 3 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The classic solution to this problem uses binary digits -- count from zero to $2^n-1$ where $n$ is the number of elements and for every value $k$ in the range include an element in the subset if the bit at position $q$ where $0\le q\le n-1$ is set.

Here is an implementation that prints all subsets of its command line arguments.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

MAIN: {
    my $n = scalar(@ARGV);

    my (@flags) = (0) x $n;

    my $pos;
    while(1){
      my @subset = ();
      for($pos=0; $pos<$n; $pos++){
          push @subset, $ARGV[$pos]
            if $flags[$pos] == 1;
      }
      print '{' . join(', ', @subset) . '}';
      print "\n";

      for($pos=0; $pos<$n; $pos++){
          if($flags[$pos] == 0){
            $flags[$pos] = 1;
            last;
          }

          $flags[$pos] = 0;
      }

      last if $pos == $n;
    }
}
```

This is what the output looks like:

```
$ ./subsets.pl a b c
{}
{a}
{b}
{a, b}
{c}
{a, c}
{b, c}
{a, b, c}
```

Comment: This can also be done by directly counting to $2^n-1$ and extracting the bits of $k$ one after the other, but the idea is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

By identifying subsets with characteristic vectors, enumerating all subsets of an $n$-element set is the same as enumerating all binary vectors of length $n$.

One way is to enumerate the numbers $0,1,\ldots,2^n-1$ in binary notation.
In many situations it is desirable to flip only a single bit going from one element to the next (correspondingly, going from one subset to the next by adding or removing only a single element). This can be achieved by the [Gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code).

Comment: I believe you mean $2^n-1$ rather than $n-1$ at the start of your second paragraph...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Thanks for spotting this. It is corrected now.

Answer (score 2):

In a very simple speech, with binary codes you can discover all of them.
for example if you want to write all subsets of a set with 2 member , you must calculate whole number from 0 to (2^2)-1 or 3.
For instance: 
Suppose set : {1,2}

```
00 -----> 0 ---> {}
01 -----> 1 ---> {1}
10 -----> 2 ---> {2}
11 -----> 3 ---> {1,2}
```

and you can continue this to end.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the set to be finite with $n$ elements in them.

Let $A$ = $(a_1, a_2,...a_n$)

Now you can have subsets of size $0$ to $n$ elements.

If the number of elements is ($n-1$) , subsets of $(n-1)$ element-ed sets are subsets of $A$ itself. This can be extended till $1$ element subsets.

**Aliter:**

You can make the $0,1, \dots n$ sets with the given elements.

Answer (score 0):

If I look into the problem in another perspective, this eventually boils down to

$$\sum_{k=0}^{|S|} {{|S|}\choose{k}}$$

And quickly solving in Python

```
>>> S = {1,2,3,4}
>>> from itertools import chain, combinations
>>> list(chain(*(list(combinations(S, n)) for n in range(0, len(S)+1))))
[(), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm is type of *finite* procedure operating on *finite* data as input and generating a *finite* output. So you can only have an algorithm to find the subsets of $\Sigma$ if $\Sigma$ is finite. (You've been given some hints for that case, but it is important to stress that these hints only work for finite $\Sigma$.)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should notice that the only subset of an empty set is the empty set itself.

Then,

1. Fix some element x of the set.
2. Generate all subsets of the set formed by removing x from the main set.
3. These subsets are subsets of the original set.
4. All of the sets formed by adding x into those subsets are subsets of the original set.

Following is an illustration:

{ A, H, I}

{    H, I}

{       I}

{        }

now, we reach the base situation, namely empty set. Then, we will add the x that we have fixed into those subsets:

{ A, H, I} ------------------------> {A,H,I},{A,H},{A,I},{A}

```
                        {H,I},{H},{I},{}
```

{    H, I} ------------------------> {H, I},  {H},

```
                      {I}, {}
```

{       I} ------------------------> {I},     {}

{        } ------------------------> {}

source: http://www.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1126/lectures/07/Slides07.pdf