# How to write "the set of all walks of a graph" in formal logic notation?

Tags: graph-theory, notation, set-theory, formal-systems

I have [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/141063/how-to-properly-conceptualize-and-formally-model-a-mathematical-definition) on the CS stackexchange to figure out how to model "a walk of a graph" in a custom formal language. I think the problem is that there is not just one walk of a graph but many (every possible walk). So I would like to learn what it looks like to write "the set of all walks of a graph" in formal logic notation. From there you can just say $w \in W$ (a walk is an element of all walks of the graph). Simple enough. A [regular definition](http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/more/mdm/sec_paths.html) of a graph walk is:

> A **walk** in a graph $G = (V, E)$ is a sequence of vertices $v_0, v_1, ..., v_n$ such that $\{v_i, v_{i+1}\} \in E$ for all $0 \leq i \lt n$.

In order to find the walks of the graph, one needs to have all possible subsets of the graph. Then filter the subsets so that you only have the ones where each pair of vertices in each subset are linked directly with an edge. It is over my head how you would write that in formal logic notation (i.e. no natural language, or minimal natural language). I would like to do that so I can see the computational tree structure of the symbols.

I was looking at [Is there an algorithm to find all subsets of a set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349220/is-there-an-algorithm-to-find-all-subsets-of-a-set), but the answer is incomplete:

> Let $S = \{1,2,3\}$. The subsets of $S$ are all subsets of $\{1,2\}$ and all subsets of $\{1,2\}$ with the element $3$ appended to each subset...

Building off that, how would you write the formal logic form of "all subsets of vertices of the graph", and then follow up with "all walks of the graph" by taking a subset of the subsets? I guess the first part is writing the definition of a [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set). Ah I guess that's not too bad!

$$P(S) = \{T : T \subseteq S\}$$

This is the powerset, now how to figure out the **powerwalk**.

Is something like this close?

$$\{X : \exists X \subseteq P(S), \forall v_1, v_2 \in X, \{v_1, v_2\} \in E\}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your trouble arises because you throw away the "temporal" structure of a walk; some vertices come before others.  Instead, consider keeping it, and annotate each vertex with where it appears in the walk:

We usually interpret walks as functions $\mathbb{N}\to G$ (or, if you are only studying finite walks, functions from $\{0,1,\dots,N\}\to G$).  Of course, not every such function is a walk, since it might "leap" from an unconnected vertex to another.  But that is easy enough to remove: $$\text{Walks}(G)=\{f:(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(f(n)\sim f(n+1))\}\subseteq(\mathbb{N}\to G)$$ where $\sim$ denotes the adjacency relation on the graph.

Since your CS stackexchange question seems to ask about enumeration, I'll add that this allows for an easy way to enumerate all possible walks:

First, store your graph in such a way that, given a vertex $v$, it is easy to compute the set $N(v)$ of all adjacent vertices.  Then, iteratively build a list:

- Initially, your list has the unique zero-length walk.
- Repeat forever (there are infinitely-many walks):

  - For each walk in the list:

    - Find the last vertex.  (If there isn't one, keep reading.)
    - Find all vertices adjacent to that vertex.  (If the previous step failed, this is every vertex.)
    - Replace the original walk in the list with the set of all *walk extensions*: that is, take the walk and append one of the adjacent vertices you previously found to the end.
  - Now, rather than a list of walks, you have a list of sets of walk extensions.  Conjoin (union) those sets into a new list.

Note that this algorithm *stratifies* the set of infinitely many walks by length: to find all walks of length $n$, just run the "infinite" loop only $n$ times.

To connect my definition to powersets: then the *trajectory* of each walk (which vertices it hits, independent of order), is just the range of $f$.  That is: $$\text{Trajectories}(G)=\{\{f(n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}:(\forall n\in\mathbb{N})(f(n)\sim f(n+1))\}$$  If you want to find the trajectory of each walk first, go for it.  But I think figuring out whether an $f$ exists that marks out your set will be tricky.  (In the finite case, at least, note that $f$ maps the natural order on $\mathbb{N}$ to a linear order on its trajectory.  So maybe you can randomly direct the graph $S$ acyclically and see if it supports a total linear order?)

Comment: How does this capture all possible walks, should it have something to do with the powerset? I read this as "the set of f, where for all n in N, if a node is adjacent to the next node, then include f, and all this is a subset of the possible functions mapping integers to graph nodes". To me this is missing the powerset functionality, and the $∼$ is hiding too much it feels like. I don't quite follow it :)

Comment: @LancePollard: No, that's exactly right.  I don't think you want to be looking at powersets, because then you have to figure out the order in which you hit those vertices.

Comment: @LancePollard: Added some comments on connection to powersets.

Comment: Also note that your "regular definition" of walks specifies that they are _sequences_ of vertices.  The usual notion of sequences keeps track of where a vertex appears in that sequence (else how do we handle duplicates?).

Comment: Can you explain more how $()∼(+1)$ works? To me in my head, that is assuming the graph nodes are in order on a line and you are just taking them in sequence. But I am imagining complex interconnected webs/graphs, there are all kinds of walks which is why I'm getting tripped up. I guess I get what you're saying about order being a separate concern/factor. A walk technically is just interconnected nodes in a sequence, not caring about the order we step through it? Wait but a sequence is an order... hmm...

Comment: @LancePollard: Yes: if you record the vertices in the order you encounter them, the walk naturally "untangles" itself.  So you only need to check whether each successive transition is allowed.  And that's what $f(n)\sim f(n+1)$ is doing: $f$ is already specified, but might not be a valid walk.  For each $n$, we check that the $n$th and $(n+1)$st vertices are adjacent.  (This requires an infinite loop inside an infinite loop, since there are infinitely many $n$ to check for each of the infinitely-many $f$ — maybe that's what's tripping you up?)

Comment: I'll add: I'm assuming it's easy to determine whether two vertices are adjacent in your graph.  If not, then all I can say is: hard problem is hard.  Asking how to minimize the number of adjacency checks is a problem better suited to CS stackexchange.

Comment: "A walk technically is just interconnected nodes in a sequence, **not caring about the order we step through it**" — **No.  Bolded part is wrong.**  Consider the $n$-cycle with self-loops added at each vertex.  How do you distinguish between the walk of length $n$ around the circle, the walk of length $2n$ produced by doing it twice, and the walk of length $2n$ produced by walking around the circle once but pausing at each vertex?

Comment: Or if you _do_ consider them the same, then that's not really what most people mean by a walk anymore.  I don't think there's a good way to enumerate them short of enumerating all walks, and then "forgetting" the order structure.

Comment: Alright I will have to let this stew. Thank you for the help I really appreciate it!